# problem with overlapping faces in modeling blender

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing, glass

today I made a 3d model,

and it looks ok, but i made it for 3d print, and in the preview window, it looks with errors:

Here the print will fill all the glass content, and i dont want that, and i notice the interior is not complete.
[image]

Here is a warning for errors in the model
[image]

im a newbie in this topic. im using blender 2.92 for moddeling

any advice is welcome :)

[.blend file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/hg7vqaf2vqld8ex/vaso2.blend/file)

Thanks for you help

Edit:
I solve it with the help of NatureK Thanks you :D,
the problem was, i have some overlapping faces in my model.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/259173/edit) and give it a meaningful title that describes briefly the problem. This way other users with a similar problem can find the question and get an answer.

Comment: @Blunder done, sorry because i don't know what was the problem, i don't know what i can put in the title

Comment: Thank you for the edit :-) When the answer below solved your problem you accept it and it will get a nice green checkmark ("solved").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to spend some time learning how to model.
In your case,you can see some slash on the side,that means there are some overlapped faces,those faces are all seperated,you can't manually delete them unless you know how they come from.What's more,from the bottom of your cup,it's not just overlapped,there are many triangles crowded there.
[image]

[image]

Comment: im goin to re do that part, thanks :)

Comment: @Luis if NatureK has answered your question it'd be helpful if you accepted it by clicking the checkmark next to it.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers